# Flex ANT task fb.exportReleaseBuild

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I am using ANT to do build several Flex projects at once.
My XML file defines a target that's a series of
fb.exportReleaseBuild tasks.

But, I am driving this with a shell script (OS X, Terminal),
not from within Eclipse.  I build the target by executing
FlashBuilder in a command line, something like

flashbuilder -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner \
         -file myXmlFile target FractionMats3

Problem is, I must run this with Eclipse closed.  Which is OK.
But I have to remember to open all the relevant project first
before closing, or flashbuilder won't build them.

is there an ANT task for opening a project?

Comment: This sounds wrong to me; I didn't think you needed to launch Flash Builder to compile Flex w/ Ant.  Have you looked at the Flex ANT Tasks?  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf678b2-7ffc.html

Comment: As I understand it, the Flex ANT tasks are run by FB.  So, I launch FB with "-application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner" in order to be able to use the Flex ANT tasks.  I don't recall where I picked up this technique, but I did not invent it.

Comment: I did not think the Flex ANT tasks had a Flash Builder Dependency; however it is not my area of expertise.